# How to iterate through two date ranges and display in ASP.NET Calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am trying to create a hotel booking calendar that selects the `DateFrom` and `DateTo`

I need to iterate through from the `DateFrom` to `DateTo` and display all these dates in the calendar, the code I have so far only selects the `DateFrom` and `DateTo` and displays them in the calendar as a label:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DateTime df = (DateTime)dr.Field<DateTime?>("DateFrom");
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)dr.Field<DateTime?>("DateTo");


        if (e.Day.Date == dt.Date)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            lbl.Text = "Booked From";
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
         }

        if (e.Day.Date == df.Date)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            lbl.Text = "Booked To";
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Booking Calendar using the Calendar Control in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952097/how-to-create-a-booking-calendar-using-the-calendar-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: What is 'ds' in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not changing your code to much I would do this:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
    DateTime df = (DateTime)dr.Field<DateTime?>("DateFrom");
    DateTime dt = (DateTime)dr.Field<DateTime?>("DateTo");

    if (e.Day.Date == dt.Date)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        lbl.Text = "Booked From";
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
     }

    if (e.Day.Date == df.Date)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        lbl.Text = "Booked To";
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }

    //Added Code
    if(e.Day.Date > df.Date && e.Day.Date < dt.Date)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        lbl.Text = "Day inbetween";
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution.

```
DateTime temp = df;

while (temp < dateTo)
{
   temp = temp.AddDays(1);
   // do something with inbetween date here...
}
```